# apache2 virtualhost redirctpermanent causing infinite loop

Tags: apache, redirect, apache2, virtualhost

I have two sub-domains pointing to same system/IP

one is say - subdomain.example.com and second is say - newsubdomain.example.com

I have written a  block for redirect permanent like this -

```
NameVirtualHost subdomain.example.com:443
<VirtualHost subdomain.example.com:443>
      ServerName subdomain.example.com
      RedirectPermanent / https://newsubdomain.example.com
      # SSL info goes here 
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName newsubdomain.example.com
      # SSL info goes here 
</VirtualHost>
```

This is causing a infinite loop, when I enter https://subdomain.example.com in the browser. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
 ServerName newexample.com
```

To:

```
 ServerName example.com
```

**Edit:**
Change:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
      ServerName newsubdomain.example.com
      # SSL info goes here 
</VirtualHost>
```

To:

```
NameVirtualHost newsubdomain.example.com:443
<VirtualHost newsubdomain.example.com:443>
      ServerName newsubdomain.example.com
      # SSL info goes here 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you put vitualhost directive of `newsubdomain.example.com` here?

Comment: I have put it up in the question itself. Please check.

Comment: When I run apachectl configtest, it gives me 3 warnings, like [warn] NameVirtualHost subdomain.example.com:443 has no VirtualHosts. Though, I have VirtualHosts defined. Any reason behind this?

Comment: I think the warnings would go away if you use `NameVirtualHost *`!

Comment: I think `NameVirtualHost` is for IP addresses, not ServerNames... therefore you only have to declare NameVirtualHost *:443 once, or if you want to virtualhost on a specific IP address like 127.0.0.1 you would use `NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443` then `<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>`  this is why you are getting the error.